# ¿puedo conocer la posición del console cursor en c?

Tags: c, windows

he encontrado la funcion `setConsoleCursorPosition` que me sirve para poner el puntero en un sitio determinado existe alguna manera de saber en que posición está el cursor de la consola. Esque lo que quiero es que se mueva dos casillas para atras pero creo que con la funcion anterior no se puede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que utilizar la función [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

Al llamar a esta funcion vas a recibir una estructura con cierta informacion rellenada, las coordenadas estan en la estructura `dwCursorPosition`

```
COORD GetConsoleCursorPosition(HANDLE hConsoleOutput)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO cbsi;
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOutput, &cbsi))
    {
        return cbsi.dwCursorPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        // The function failed. Call GetLastError() for details.
        COORD invalid = { 0, 0 };
        return invalid;
    }
}
```